# php cli not recognize function inside file

Tags: php, laravel, command-line-interface

I am trying to check what will be the result of MySQL query inside Laravel FW. I develop a file for this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illumunate\Http\Request;

function DBTest(){
    echo "test1 \n";

    $DBTickers [] = DB::table('stocks')->select('id')->get();

    echo "test2 \n";
    echo $DBTickers;
}
?>
```

my problem is that I can't call DBTest from CLI. I try:

```
php -f ./dbTest.php DBTest -> nothing prints

php --run "require './dbTest.php'; DBTest();"`
```

> ->PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function DBTest() in Command line code on line 1

```
php -r 'include ("./dbTest.php"); DBTest();'
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function DBTest() in Command line code on line 1

If I comment the "namespace" and "use" directives and I can call DBTest().

So, My question is is there a way (syntax) that can call the DBTest function from CLI while the "namespace" and "use" are presented?

Comment: What exactly do you need the function for? Why not use a Laravel Artisan Command? `php -f ./dbTest.php DBTest` That second parameter `DBTest` will not run your function, it's a parameter

Comment: Include the namespace in your call ...? `App\Http\Controllers\DBTest()`

Comment: There are more issues. PHP won't know where to find `Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB` (or any other external class). You either need to include all files yourself or include composers autoloader. Then you also need to boot up Laravel, so it can read the config files to get the connection details. You can do all that manually, but that would be unnecessary. As previous comment mentioned, create an [artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/artisan) instead and it will solve the above issues.

Comment: How about `php artisan tinker` ?